# Javascript: Text Area Parsing

Tags: javascript, function, parsing

I am making a filter for a project I'm making.

I am looking for a way to do this without going and defining everything in different variables for every character I want to change.

I don't want to do it this way:

```
function clean(n){
        var textfield = document.getElementById(n);
        var regex = /</gi;
        textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "&lt;");
        var regex1 = />/gi;
        textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex1, "&gt;");
    }
```

How would I do this without setting up everything as different variables and make it so that it'll replace a specific character with a different specific character than it just replacing a range of characters with one specific character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an Example: The top part contains a few utility-functions that are intended to make your life easier

The bottom part implements a custom escaping function like the one you're asking for, and as a samnple it takes the innerHTML of the Demo  and prints the escaped result.

```js
// general utilities

// returns a function that performs some replace task, ...
const replace = (needle, replacement) => value => value.replace(needle, replacement);
// ... like escaping strings for RegExp
const escapeRegExp = replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');

const sortByLengthDesc = (a, b) => b.length - a.length;
const replaceKeysWithValues = (map) => {
  return replace(
    new RegExp(Object.keys(map).sort(sortByLengthDesc).map(escapeRegExp).join("|"), "g"),
    (key) => map[key]
  );
};



// definition of the escaping to perform
const escapeTextfieldValue = replaceKeysWithValues({
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  //feel free to add more pairs to replace
});


// using document.body.innerHTML as a sample text that needs to be escaped
// and writing the result into the <pre>-tag
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = escapeTextfieldValue(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h4>Escaped Text</h4>
<pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const replaceMap = {
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
};

function escape(str) {
  return Object.keys(replaceMap).reduce((result, symbol) => {
    return result.replace(new RegExp(symbol, 'g'), replaceMap[symbol]);
  }, str);
}
```